# python mysql loop progressively slow down on delete statement

Tags: mysql

I have a simple delete statement. It works fast about the first 100 deletes.  Then it slows down, then it will sped up. Explain looks pretty fast but the deletes are slow.

```
for loop
    delete from data.stafftable where staffname='something' and time_deleted<now() and staff_type='teach';
```

Explain

```
id: 1
select_type: DELETE
table: stafftable
partitions: NULL
type: range
possible_keys: PRIMARY,staff_name_index,time_deleted_index
key: PRIMARY
key_len: 7
ref: const
rows: 1
filtered: 100.00
```

Comment: Its probably due to your delete forcing the server to do heavy lifting with a string search and date comparison versus looking up by a primary key integer.   Also,  you didn't end the loop?  
begin_label: LOOP
statement_list
END LOOP end_label
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql_loop_statement.htm

Comment: Are you doing it with a different `staffname` each time? Why not do them all at once with `where staffname in ('something', 'something else', ...)`?

Comment: yes staff name is different each loop.  this was just an example.  also i shorten the python loop in the for statement just for brevity.

Answer (score 1):

The more you do it, the more it has to step over rows that it does not need to delete.  Whether the table has `INDEX(time_deleted)` or no useful index, it will get slower and slower.

This would speed it up significantly:

```
INDEX(staff_type, staffname, time_deleted)
```

With this index, each time you run the `DELETE`, the *first* row it encounters will satisfy the deletion criteria.  No need to skip over rows with different staff names or types but matching timestamps.

You may as well add `LIMIT 100` to the `DELETE` statement.  Then it will clean up the table much faster.  (No, do not fall into the trap of "the bigger the better".)

Oh, now I see the hidden information -- that staffname changes as you delete.  The `LIMIT 100` may or may not help; but it should not hurt.

(No, "string compares" is not the reason for the slowdown.)

Comment: Thank you i was leaning towards a combo index, but I think time_deleted should do the tick as well.  But thank you and I will add this combo index and see if that works.